# Tornado Web custom 404 where path does not exist

Tags: python, tornado

I am trying to change the native 404 response that Tornado web Application instance gives when it fails to route (or acknowledge Content-Type json).

I could not find documentation to do this, so am right now just adding a final regex that matches everything:

```
import tornado.web

class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def write_error(self, status_code, **kwargs):
        self.finish({
            'error': {
                'code': status_code,
                'message': self._reason,
            }
        })


class NotFoundHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise tornado.web.HTTPError(
            status_code=404,
            reason="Invalid resource path."
        )


app = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/ping", PingHandler),
    # ...
    (r"(.*)", NotFoundHandler),
])
```

This feels like a bit of a hack. Is there a way to more globally set this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/structure.html) you can use `default_handler_class` to do this.

> For 404 errors, use the `default_handler_class` Application setting.
>   This handler should override `prepare` instead of a more specific
>   method like `get()` so it works with any HTTP method. It should
>   produce its error page as described above: either by raising a
>   `HTTPError(404)` and overriding `write_error`, or calling
>   `self.set_status(404)` and producing the response directly in
>   `prepare()`.

So for example:

```
class NotFoundHandler(RequestHandler):
    def prepare(self):  # for all methods
        raise tornado.web.HTTPError(
            status_code=404,
            reason="Invalid resource path."
        )

app = Application(..., default_handler_class=NotFoundHandler)
```

Comment: Not sure how I missed that param-- exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A adapted version of your code worked for me:

```
...
class NotFoundHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("404.html")


app = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/ping", PingHandler),
   # ...
  (r"/.*", NotFoundHandler),
])
```